# Android Espresso IntentsTestRule does not record intents when run on Marshmallow Emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-espresso

We have a large suite of Espresso tests for our application that run successfully on KitKat and Lollipop emulators.

Today we've tried to migrate our testing emulator to a Marshmallow device and non of the IntentsTestRule's are recording their intents.

We are using Genymotion.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with using a fragment context instead of an activity context. The way I fixed the problem was to do the following in my fragment.

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

I get no recorded intents if I leave off the getActivty() part and use the fragment's context to start the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue that Google is working on fixing, see this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202217&q=espresso&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).